# Swedish characters and Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am using Robot framework for test automation of an application in Swedish.
I want to enter swedish text into textbox. The text contains special characters of swedish language like Ä,Ö,Å.

For example, I want to enter text "**STÖDE**" .but it enters text as "**ST\xd6DE**".
Please let me know how to enter correct characters.
My code is as following:

```
Input Text    ${objectName}    STÖDE
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code in your question?

Comment: Have you checked the encoding of the .robot itself? If this file format does not support it, you may see these kinds of characters. An alternative is to read your string from a file using `Get File` into a variable.

Comment: \xd6 is unicode hex for Ö ..  If it comes like that to your application, either your application doesnt know how to handle unicode or you are running python2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just version problem I amm using **Robot Framework 4.0 (Python 3.8.5 on linux)**. I had no problem entering STÖDE to variouse fields.
I downloaded example to robot framework library and modified it to enter your text. It was entered without a problem.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${text}    STÖDE

*** Test Cases ***
Google Devops And Input Text
    Open Browser To Google
    Go To Search Field


*** Keywords ***
Open Browser To Google
    Open Browser    https://www.google.com    browser=firefox
    Maximize Browser Window
    Google Should Be Open

Go To Search Field
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    //*[@id="L2AGLb"]/div
    Click Element    //*[@id="L2AGLb"]/div
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]   
    Input Text    xpath=//body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input    ${text}


Google Should Be Open
    Location Should Contain    www.google.com
```